# Try block continues after catch

Tags: c++, exception

In an overloaded `operator[]` function, I have the following block of code:

```
try {       
   if (index < 0 || index >= n)
      throw new std::out_of_range("Invalid index!");
   return arr[index];   
}   
catch(std::out_of_range& ex)  { 
   cout << ex.what() << endl;   
}
```

The function is called with

```
cout << arr[-1];
```

which results in an **unhandled** `std::out_of_range` exception. After inspecting the code execution, it turned out that after the `throw`, the execution doesn't go to the `catch` block, but straight to the `return` statement.

I don't usually catch exceptions in the same function, this was for testing purposes only and I want to understand what is going on.

Comment: (1) remove the `new` in `throw new std::out_of_range("Invalid index!");` and (2) change `catch(std::out_of_range& ex)` to `catch(std::out_of_range const & ex)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not

```
throw new std::out_of_range("Invalid index!");
```

but

```
throw std::out_of_range("Invalid index!");
```

To elaborate in your code you are catching type `std::out_of_range&` but throwing type `std::out_of_range*`. And as is pointed out in the comments there's no good reason not to catch `const std::out_of_range&`

Comment: Totally overlooked the fact I was throwing an object created with new, so I should catch a pointer type. If we were to throw an object in this manner, I assume it should be explicitly destroyed in the catch block. What would be practical purposes of handling exceptions this way?

Comment: Normal C++ practice is to throw objects but catch by reference (so you don't get problems with object slicing). Objects are copied when thrown so if you throw a pointer then I suppose you avoid that. I think you should delete the exception object explicitly but in fact you don't know for sure in the catch block that the object has been dynamically allocated. Hard to see that there is really any benefit, I would stick to objects.